# Can't understand why 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence' is accured

Tags: python, numpy

I get 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence' about lines 2 and 4 and can't understand why...

```
m_v[0, int(v), int(parent)] = psi_v[0, int(v)] * get_p_e_u_v(parent, v, 0, 0) +\
                              psi_v[1, int(v)] * get_p_e_u_v(parent, v, 0, 1)
m_v[1, int(v), int(parent)] = psi_v[0, int(v)] * get_p_e_u_v(parent, v, 1, 0) +\
                              psi_v[1, int(v)] * get_p_e_u_v(parent, v, 1, 1)
```

```
def get_p_e_u_v(u, v, xu, xv):
    if xu != xv:
        return_p_e = p_e[func(int(u), int(v))]
    else:
        return_p_e = 1.0 - p_e[func(int(u), int(v))]
    return return_p_e
```

func returns an int in range (0, len(p_e))

Comment: Full traceback/error message please!

Comment: It's likely that `m_v[0, int(v), int(parent)]` references one element of `m_v`, while the RHS expression produces an array, or at least more than one element.  You need to check the size of the both sides of those equations.